# Query to get the most reacted post and its reactions

Tags: mysql

I have a table named posts:

```
table.increments(`post_id`).
table.text('post')
table.string('file_path')
table.integer('user_id')
```

And a table named reactions:

```
table.increments(`reaction_id`).primary()
table.integer(`post_id`)
table.integer(`user_id`)
table.integer(`reaction`)
```

My goal is to get the posts with most reactions for like, dislike and heart together with the post_id.

Therefore, it would look like:

```
{
  likes: 300,
  most_liked_post_id: 3,
  most_liked_user_id: 21,
  hearts: 400,
  most_heart_post_id: 4,
  most_heart_user_id: 29,
  dislikes: 300,
  most_disliked_post_id: 3,
  most_disliked_user_id: 21,
}
```

I tried this:

```
SELECT 
  SUM(reaction = 1) AS likes,
  SUM(reaction = 2) AS hearts,
  SUM(reaction = 3) AS dislikes 
FROM
  reactions 
GROUP BY posts_id
```

but it seems I am going nowhere with this. I used that as a subquery to get the max likes, hearts and dislikes but it seems wrong because they all appear to have the same number.

> Update

Thanks to sir @Martin I came up to this:

```
SELECT 
  l.posts_id AS like_post,
  l.count AS like_count,
  l.user_id AS like_user_id,
  h.posts_id AS heart_post,
  h.count AS heart_count,
  h.user_id AS heart_user_id,
  d.posts_id AS dislike_post,
  d.count AS dislike_count,
  d.user_id AS dislike_user_id
FROM
  (SELECT 
    posts_id, COUNT(*) AS COUNT, user_id 
  FROM
    reactions 
  WHERE reaction = 1 
  GROUP BY posts_id 
  ORDER BY 2 DESC 
  LIMIT 1) l

  INNER JOIN (SELECT 
    posts_id, COUNT(*) AS COUNT, user_id 
  FROM
    reactions 
  WHERE reaction = 2 
  GROUP BY posts_id 
  ORDER BY 2 DESC 
  LIMIT 1) h

  INNER JOIN (SELECT 
    posts_id, COUNT(*) AS COUNT, user_id 
  FROM
    reactions 
  WHERE reaction = 3 
  GROUP BY posts_id 
  ORDER BY 2 DESC 
  LIMIT 1) d
```

Comment: could you please provide some sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited following OP comment**

I misunderstood the original requirement and had a query that listed the likes, hearts, and dislikes for all posts.

Now I've updated the query to simply return the most liked, most hearted, and most disliked post:

```
SELECT  a.post_id AS MostLikedPost,
        a.LikeCount,
        b.post_id AS MostHeartedPost,
        b.HeartCount,
        c.post_id AS MostDislikedPost,
        c.DislikeCount
  FROM  (
        SELECT  post_id,
                COUNT(*) AS LikeCount
          FROM  reactions
          WHERE reaction = 1
          GROUP BY post_id
          ORDER BY 2 DESC
          LIMIT 1
        ) a
    LEFT JOIN (
              SELECT  post_id,
                      COUNT(*) AS HeartCount
                FROM  reactions
                WHERE reaction = 2
                GROUP BY post_id
                ORDER BY 2 DESC
                LIMIT 1
              ) b ON 1 = 1
    LEFT JOIN (
              SELECT  post_id,
                      COUNT(*) AS DislikeCount
                FROM  reactions
                WHERE reaction = 3
                GROUP BY post_id
                ORDER BY 2 DESC
                LIMIT 1
              ) c ON 1 = 1
```

The query uses three sub-queries, each of which find the maximum in each of the reaction categories.  The results are then amalgamated into a single output.

Note: Code is untested as there is no sample data or expected output.

Comment: I think you misunderstood sir. This query counts all the reactions grouped by reaction. Similar to `select count(reaction) from reactions group by reaction`. All I need is to get the post with most likes, dislikes and hearts.

Comment: Ahhh i see. Wait lemme refactor and give the result

Comment: @MarielleMaeValdez I did misunderstand, sorry. I've updated the question with a query that now outputs one line with the requested informtation for the most liked, most hearted, and most disliked post.

Comment: thank you sir! You are right. Your first answer gave me the idea of how to apply your second answer.